# Analytic Functional Calculus on C*-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Here is one of the practice questions that I have been trying from my C*-algebras exercises.

Suppose that $T\in L(X)$ and $f\in H(T)$. Prove that $f(T^*) = f(T)^*$

In this situation $H(T)$ represents all functions that are analytic around a neighborhood of $\sigma(T)$. I tried to use continuous functional calculus here, but that is only applicable for normal elements. So, I feel like I should be using the analytic functional calculus. But I can't make this work since $\sigma(T)$ need not be equal to $\sigma(T^*)$.

Any hints on how to proceed will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I'm interested in how you define $f(T)$.

Comment: The formula is wrong. I guess you should prove that $f(T)^*=f^*(T^*),$ where $f^*(z)=\bar{f}(\bar{z})$